# logical deduction - Persian Rugs - A Zebra Puzzle (Einstein's Riddle) Variation

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play this Zebra Puzzle here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/persian-rugs/

|  | Client #1 | Client #2 | Client #3 | Client #4 | Client #5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| color |  |  |  |  |  |
| name |  |  |  |  |  |
| type |  |  |  |  |  |
| symbols |  |  |  |  |  |
| price |  |  |  |  |  |
| place |  |  |  |  |  |

Five men, who just bought Persian rugs, are side by side. Each one bought a very specific Persian rug for his home. Try to find out which are the characteristics from Timothy's new rug.

- Color: Blue, Green, Orange, Red, Yellow
- Name: Bryan, Casey, Garrett, Shane, Timothy
- Type: Oval, Rectangular, Round, Runner, Square
- Symbols: Birds, Diamonds, Lotuses, Roses, Stars
- Price: 400 dollars, 600 dollars, 800 dollars, 1000 dollars, 2000 dollars
- Place: Bedroom, Hall, Library, Living Room, Office

Clues:

1. The man who bought the 400 dollar rug is exactly to the left of the man who bought the rug with Birds.
2. Bryan is next to the client that got the Runner rug.
3. The Red rug's owner is somewhere to the left of the man who bought a rug for his Hall.
4. The buyer who got the most expensive rug is next to the buyer who got the Round rug.
5. The Yellow rug's owner is somewhere between the Oval rug's owner and the man that spent 800 dollars, in that order.
6. The man that bought the Red rug is exactly to the left of the man that bought a rug for his Office.
7. Garrett is next to the customer who spent 600 dollars.
8. Shane is somewhere to the right of the Orange rug's owner.
9. The cheapest rug has Stars on it.
10. At the fifth position is the client who bought the Rectangular rug.
11. The man who bought the 600 dollar rug is exactly to the left of the man who bought the rug with Roses.
12. Casey is somewhere to the right of the customer that got the Yellow rug.
13. The buyer who purchased the Round rug is exactly to the left of the man who spent $800.
14. The man that bought the cheapest rug is exactly to the left of the man that acquired the Square rug.
15. At the third position is the man that got a rug for his Bedroom.
16. The customer that bought the rug with Stars is exactly to the right of the customer that bought the Green rug.
17. Shane is next to the man who acquired the Round rug.
18. The man who got the rug with Birds is somewhere between the man who got the Yellow rug and the man who got the rug with Lotuses, in that order.
19. The customer that spent 800 dollars is somewhere to the right of the Red rug's owner.
20. The client that bought a rug for his Living room is exactly to the right of the client that bought a rug for his Library.

Answer (score 1):

> Clues 10 and 15 can be plugged directly into the grid.

> #1 isn't Bedroom (clue 15), Hall (clue 3), Living Room (clue 20), or Office (clue 6), so it's Library, Living Room is #2, and Hall / Office are #4 / #5 in some order.

> Red is left of Hall (clue 3) and Office (clue 6), so it's #3, Office is #4, and Hall is #5.

> $400 = Stars (clue 9) is one to the left of Birds = Square (clues 1 and 14), and one to the right of Green (clue 16), so it's #2 or #3.

> Birds isn't #4 (no location for Yellow would fit both clue 5 and clue 18), so it's #3.

> $800 is #4 or #5 (clue 19). It's not #4 (clue 13), so it's #5 and Round is #4.

> $1200 is #3 (clue 4).

> The 600 dollar rug is not #1 (clue 11), so it's #4, $1000 is #1, and Roses are #5.

> Shane and Garrett are #3 and #5 in some order (clues 7 and 17), so Casey can only be #4 (clue 12), Yellow is #2, Lotuses is #4 (clue 18), and Diamonds is #1.

> Orange is #4 (clue 8), Shane is #5, and Garrett is #3.

> Oval is #1 (clue 5), Runner is #2, Bryan is #1 (clue 2), and that locks in the remaining choices.

> Timothy's attributes are Yellow, Runner, Stars, $400, and Living Room.